# Globally Unique Identifier in Vertica

Tags: vertica, vsql

I am going to create some table at Vertica Database on which i have to give Global Unique Identifier to identify each row uniquely.  Please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Sequences/UsingNamedSequences.htm):

Types of Incrementing Value Objects

- Named sequences are database objects that generate unique numbers in ascending or descending sequential order. They are most often used when an application requires a unique identifier in a table or an expression. Once a named sequence returns a value, it never returns that same value again. Named sequences are independent objects, and while you can use their values in tables, they are not subordinate to them.
- Auto-increment column value: a sequence available only for numeric column types. Auto-increment sequences automatically assign the next incremental sequence value for that column when a new row is added to the table.
- Identity column: a sequence available only for numeric column types.

Comment: Thanks Kermit. Has Vertica contains any function like NEWID() in sql server?

Comment: @San No it does not. See sequences in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A named sequence is what you are looking for. You can use the same sequence for multiple tables:

```
-- 2 tables...
CREATE TABLE tst  (id INT, value varchar(10));
CREATE TABLE tst2 (id INT, value varchar(10));

-- 1 sequence...
CREATE SEQUENCE tst_seq;

-- ... said sequence is used by both tables
ALTER TABLE tst  ALTER COLUMN id set default NEXTVAL('tst_seq');
ALTER TABLE tst2 ALTER COLUMN id set default NEXTVAL('tst_seq');

-- testing...
INSERT INTO tst (value) VALUES ('tst');
INSERT INTO tst2 (value) VALUES ('tst2');

-- success!
=> SELECT * FROM tst;
 id |  value
----+---------
  1 | tst
(1 row)

=> SELECT * FROM tst2;
 id |  value
----+----------
  2 | tst2
(1 row)
```

Then `NEXTVAL('named_sequence')`, here used during table creation, is the equivalent of `NEWID()` you are looking for.